# Another 'x was not declared in this scope'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

this is my first question here.

Writing some code, i receive this error from g++: "Entity was not declared in this scope", in this context:

```
#ifndef Psyco2D_GameManager_
#define Psyco2D_GameManager_

#include <vector>
#include "Entity.h"

namespace Psyco2D{
    class GameManager{J
    private:
        std::vector<Entity> entities;
    };
}

#endif
```

This is the content of Entity.h:

```
#ifndef Psyco2D_Entity_
#define Psyco2D_Entity_

#include <string>
#include "GameManager.h"
#include "EntityComponent.h"


namespace Psyco2D{

    class Entity{
        friend class GameManager;

    private:
        /* Identificatore */
        std::string _name;

        /* Components list */
        std::map<const std::string, EntityComponent*> components;

    protected:
        Entity(const std::string name);

    public:
        inline const std::string getName() const{
            return this->_name;
        }

        void addComponent(EntityComponent* component, const std::string name);

        EntityComponent* lookupComponent(const std::string name) const;

        void deleteComponent(const std::string name);

    };

}

#endif
```

If i use `std::vector<class Entity>` instead of `std::vector<Entity>` it works.

Why?

Thanks to all =)

Comment: How are we to guess what `"Entity.h"` contains?

Comment: Sorry, i edited the message =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the first snippet is part of `GameManager.h` you have a circular header dependency. I believe you can fix this by changing the `GameManager.h` include in `Entity.h` to `class GameManager;` instead.

Additionally as GMan noted, Entity is in a namespace and you need to qualify Entity with the namespace name.

Comment: It isn't the problem, i have in GameManager header preprocessor ifndef and define directives like in Entity.h

Comment: @Sigel: It *is* the problem. :) I walked you through it on my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you have a cyclic dependency. Take out `#include "GameManager.h"` in `Entity.h`, since you don't actually need it in that header. (Up-vote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326717/another-x-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/3327088#3327088), which first pointed it out.)

Note the guards are actually the problem; but don't take them out! You just need to minimize the includes you have, and declare (and not define) types when possible. Consider what happens when you include `Entity.h`: As some point it includes `GameManager.h`, which in turn includes `Entity.h`. At this point, `Entity.h` already has its header guard defined, so it skips the contents. Then the parsing of `GameManager.h` continues, where upon it runs into `Entity`, and rightfully complains it is not defined. (Indeed, this is still the process of including `GameManager.h` in the first inclusion of `Entity.h`, far before `Entity` is defined!)

Note your numerous edits demonstrate why it's important to post real code, not re-synthesized code. You need real details to get real answers.

---

<sub>Old:</sub>

`Entity` is in the `Psyco2D` namespace. You need to specify that:

```
class GameManager{
private:
    std::vector<Psyco2D::Entity> entities;
};
```

Comment: Sorry and sorry again, i miss a part of code... The GameManager class is in Psyco2D namespace too

Comment: Ehi, it works, thanks for the explanation. I vote Mark B's answer because, as you told, first pointed it out. Thanks Mark B =)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Psyco2D-namespace and it will work without declaring "class Entity".